# How to work with the python sqlite output data?

Tags: python, database

I need a help with Python3.7 sqlite3 database. I have created it, inserted some data in it but I am not able to work with these data then.

E. g.

```
test = db.execute("SELECT MESSAGE from TEST")
for row in test:
      print(row[0])
```

This is the only thing I’ve found. But what if I want to work with the data? What if I now want to make something like:

```
if (row[0] == 1):
    ...
```

I could not do it that way. It does not work. Can you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database queries returned as array of the rows. And each row is array of received column values.

More correctly `test` is tuple or tuples, but let's keep it simple.

In your example could be many rows, each with a single column of data.

To access first row:

```
test[0]
```

To access data in the second row:

```
test[1][0]
```

Your example:

```
if (test[0][0] == 1):
    ...
```

I hope that helped.